# How to use composition instead of inheritance when dependency injection is involved?

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, dependency-injection, composition

I have a bunch of checkers in my program that I modelled as classes: check the RAM is OK, check the disk is OK, check the temperatures are OK, etc. These checkers have a lot in common, so I modelled them with inheritance: all that is in common goes into a base class `CheckerBase` that is derived from by specialised classes with checker-specific functionality and dependencies.

However I've often read that composition should be preferred over inheritance, so I'm wondering how this would be done in C++ with composition?

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

/** Dependencies of various checkers that I pass in via dependency injection. */
struct ErrorReporter {
    void report_error(string myMsg) {
        cout << myMsg;
    }
};
struct TemperatureSensor {
    int get_cpu_temp() { return 42; }
    int get_disk_temp() { return 32; }
};
struct DiskStressor {
    void stress_disk() { }
};

/** Contains dependencies that are common to all checkers.. */
class CheckerBase {
public:
    CheckerBase(ErrorReporter* errReporter ) :
        mErrReporter(errReporter) { }

    virtual void runTest() = 0;
protected:
    ErrorReporter* mErrReporter;
};

/** Needs `TemperatureSensor` dependency. */
class TemperatureChecker : public CheckerBase {
public:
    TemperatureChecker(ErrorReporter* errReporter,
                       TemperatureSensor* tempSensor) :
        CheckerBase(errReporter), mTempSensor(tempSensor) { }

    void runTest() override {
        if (mTempSensor->get_cpu_temp() > 42) {
            mErrReporter->report_error("CPU too hot");
        }
     };
private:
    TemperatureSensor* mTempSensor;
};

/** Needs `TemperatureSensor` and `DiskStressor` dependencies. */
class DiskChecker : public CheckerBase {
public:
    DiskChecker(ErrorReporter* errReporter, TemperatureSensor* tempSensor,
                DiskStressor* diskStressor) :
        CheckerBase(errReporter), mTempSensor(tempSensor) { }

    void runTest() override {
        mDiskStressor->stress_disk();
        mTempSensor->get_disk_temp();
        if (mTempSensor->get_cpu_temp() > 32) {
            mErrReporter->report_error("HDD too hot after strees test");
        }
     };
private:
    TemperatureSensor* mTempSensor;
    DiskStressor* mDiskStressor;
};

/** Periodically runs each checker. */
class MasterChecker {
    public:
        MasterChecker() :
            mTempChecker { &mErrReporter, &mTempSensor },
            mDiskChecker { &mErrReporter, &mTempSensor, &mDiskStressor },
            mAllCheckers({&mTempChecker, &mDiskChecker}) {};

        void start() {
            // In reality I use a timer that continously runs each checker at
            // a certain interval.
            while (true) {
                for (CheckerBase *checker : mAllCheckers) {
                    checker->runTest();
                }
                this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(5000));
            }
        }
    private:
        ErrorReporter mErrReporter;
        TemperatureSensor mTempSensor;
        DiskStressor mDiskStressor;

        DiskChecker mDiskChecker;
        TemperatureChecker mTempChecker;

        vector<CheckerBase*> mAllCheckers;
};

int main() {
    MasterChecker master;
    master.start();
}
```

EDIT: Updated to include an approximation of how the checkers are used. A `MasterChecker` runs all the individual checkers periodically. It has a list of the checkers and calls their `runTest()` member function--which all checkers override from their base class.

Comment: This snippet doesn't make much sense to me: how do you extract information from your checkers? Where is the isOK() method?

Comment: @YSC It's just an example how the inheritance is modelled. Pretend that the dependencies have functions that do stuff that the checker classes use. Or I should improve my snippet somehow?

Comment: The way you intend to use your classes is paramount to come up with a composition-based design.

Comment: @YSC Thanks for the feedback, I added an approximation of how the checkers are used so that it's still an MVCE.

Comment: Your usage or inheritance is correct here. You cannot have abstract member, so you could not have member `CheckerBase`  for composition anyway.

Comment: Composition should be preferred when you're trying to _combine_ things. You're already doing this in `MasterChecker`, because you compose/aggregate the various checkers, instead of deriving from them. Implementing an abstract interface is not composition, and inheritance is fine for that.

Comment: @Jarod42 Useless Hmm I see, thank you all for the answers. If you submit these I will upvote them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ... composition should be preferred over inheritance

That means, *where you could choose either, prefer composition*. In this case, `MasterChecker` (correctly) composes the various concrete checkers, as your advice recommended.

The fact that the individual checkers inherit/implement an abstract base class isn't a problem, because you can't *compose* an interface. There's no choice here, and the advice didn't say you should never use inheritance even when composition isn't an alternative.

The case your advice actually warns against is doing something like:

```
class MasterChecker: public DiskChecker, public TemperatureChecker
```

where inheritance is abused to aggregate the base class subobjects.

In your case this probably wouldn't work well anyway, at least without changes, due to initialization order and diamond-shaped inheritance reasons.